# split .svn and working directories

Tags: svn, version-control

SVN creates .svn directory in the root directory where the local working copy directories are. Is it possible to move .svn into different directory to have clean directory with working copy?
Let say I have such directories structure:

`- Foo
    - .svn (for working_copy_from_svn_repository)
    - working_copy_from_svn_repository`

but I would like to have:

`- Foo
    - working_copy_from_svn_repository
- Bar
    - .svn (for working_copy_from_svn_repository)`

Is it possible? If not then do you know any version-control system which allows to move its local control files into particular location?

Comment: What's the use case for this? I guess that the task you need to complete has an easier solution than the one you think of.

Comment: @bahrep Let say that User1 have rights to read/write Foo but he doesn't commit anything (he even doesn't know that it's connected with any repository). There is also User2 (every-day system task) who has to commit all changes from Foo but it has read-only rights for Foo and read-write for Bar. Just interpret it as a silly system for versioned backup.

Comment: why not set `Deny` - `Full Access` rule to `.svn` for all users except User2?

Comment: @bahrep I would like to avoid any clue that there is svn around Foo content. Of course you are right and it would work. So, just out of curiosity, is there any versioning system which can store metadata far away from working copy?

Comment: I guess that there is such vcs but I can't point to any.

Comment: BTW, it looks like that you are looking for an automated backup system, not for a version-control.

Comment: @bahrep True. However, it could be just simple script + SVN with moved metadata (well, if possible ;) ). I don't need any fancy backup system, but versioning is a must.

Comment: you can't do it in SVN, but can 1) `xcopy foo bar` 2) use Git, where `GIT_DIR` ay define custom location of repository outside casual `.git` subdir

Comment: @LazyBadger I don't want to copy Foo (or I don't understand xcopy), I want to use it directly as working copy. However, GIT_DIR sounds promisingly, I will try it. Thanks!

Comment: Did my answer help you in 2014? Please, upvote it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is an easy way to move `.svn` metadata directory to another location. Such customization may require major rework of Apache Subversion working copy code.

PS Out of curiosity I've just tried to create a directory junction on Windows with `mklink` and it doesn't help. It *may* work on *nix systems, though.

Comment: I've just tried directory junction not for .svn but for working copy and it works OK. It seems that it will be possible to create virtual directory structure using junctions and then add it into SVN repository. Thanks!

Comment: @Bogdan test such solution thoroughly! I think that there could be unexpected side-effects with such solution.